# What better way to get around the "static variables" in Python?

Tags: python

It seems that in Python, to declare a variable in a class, it is static (keeps its value in the next instances). What better way to get around this problem?

```
class Foo():
  number = 0
  def set(self):
    self.number = 1


>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.number
0
>>> foo.set()
>>> foo.number
1
>>> new_foo = Foo()
>>> new_foo.number
1
```

Comment: While there is a shared `Foo.number` and you usually don't want that, it's not as bad as in your example. At the end `new_foo.number` will be 0.

Comment: Did you test the code you posted?  `new_foo.number` should not be 1 in this case.

Comment: If I run your code 

  new_foo.number  

is zero. 

As you want it to be!

Where is the problem?

Comment: "What better way to get around this problem?" - Which part of this behaviour do you consider a problem?  And what is the desired result after getting around it?

Comment: foo = Foo() provides an instance without a number attribute. When you ask for self.number since there is not the instance one you get the class one. When you set self.number the attribute number is given to self and Foo.number is kind of overriden...

Comment: @ShankarCabus Did you give a try to my answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Variables defined at the class level are indeed "static", but I don't think they work quite the way you think they do.  There are 2 levels here which you need to worry about.  There are attributes at the *class* level, and there are attributes at the *instance* level.  Whenever you do `self.attribute = ...` inside a method, you're setting an attribute at the instance level.  Whenever python looks up an attribute, it first looks at the instance level, if it doesn't find the attribute, it looks at the class level.

This can be a little confusing (especially if the attribute is a reference to a *mutable* object).  consider:

```
class Foo(object):
    attr = []  #class level attribute is Mutable
    def __init__(self):
        # in the next line, self.attr references the class level attribute since
        # there is no instance level attribute (yet)
        self.attr.append('Hello')
        self.attr = []
        # Now, we've created an instance level attribute, so further appends will
        # append to the instance level attribute, not the class level attribute.
        self.attr.append('World')

a = Foo()
print (a.attr)  #['World']
print (Foo.attr) #['Hello']
b = Foo()
print (b.attr)  #['World']
print (Foo.attr) #['Hello', 'Hello']
```

As others have mentioned, if you want an attribute to be specific to an instance, just initialize it as an instance attribute in `__init__` (using `self.attr = ...`).  `__init__` is a special method which is run whenever a class is initialized (with a few exceptions that we won't discuss here).

e.g.

```
class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.attr = 0
```

Comment: Good answer.  To clarify, to "if you want an attribute to be specific to an instance, just initialize it as an instance attribute in __init__." I would add "and make it an instance attribute using 'self.'".  Otherwise, the attribute will "disappear" when __init__ exits.

Answer (score 1):

Just leave the declaration out. If you want to provide default values for the variables, initialize them in the `__init__` method instead.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 0

    def set(self):
        self.number = 1

>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.number
0
>>> foo.set()
>>> foo.number
1
>>> new_foo = Foo()
>>> new_foo.number
0
```

**Edit**: replaced last line of the above snippet; it used to read `1` although it was just a typo on my side. Seems like it has caused quite a bit of confusion while I was away.

Comment: This doesn't work as advertised - new_foo.number is 0, not 1. Are you trying to make it static?

Comment: But not the way your example says it does.

Comment: @delnan, my example? I suppose Shankar wanted the 0 1 1 behavior... and I do provide it

Comment: Let's be clear. `Foo().number` is 0 with your definition of `Foo`, but according to the last three lines of your post it is 1. This is contradictory, only one is true. And jterrace, me, and my Python interpreter say the latter is false.

Comment: @delnan I insist: give a look at my class!

Comment: I did. Several times. I also copied and pasted it into the interactive prompt. I get 0 1 0, and no language change in the last ten years of so has any effect on the outcome. Now I even put it onto [ideone](http://ideone.com/jskNo) for you to see. Try it out instead of claiming. I'd downvote you again if I could.

Comment: @jimifiki, I want the new instance has number equals 0, not number equals 1!

Comment: @delnan jimifiki gave an answer that is not the one of this thread!! I'm not Tamas...

Comment: @jimifiki Oh, pardon me. Your code indeed works as advertised. But why are you promoting your answer in the comments regarding another answer?

Comment: @delnan, sorry, I cannot understand why people not even read my answer. Anyway it looks like the question already gave the desired behavior. I cannot understand, I think I'll quit with this no-question

Comment: @jimifiki, Your code is equivalent to mine. I don't want that a new instantiated object keep the value setted in the previous instance.

Comment: @ShankarCabus Your code it not equivalent to jimifiki (`Foo.number` instead of `self.number` in `set`). It is probably not the cleanest solution for what you actually want, but it does give 0 1 0.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe want to change the class attribute:

```
class Foo():
    number = 0
    def set(self):
        Foo.number = 1
```

instead of overriding it!

Comment: Same problem, @jimifiki. When instantiate a new Foo, number is 1, not 0.