# How to declare a member of 'list' in a class?

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and it really confused me.

I want to write something like

```
class line :
    points = []

    def add(self, point) :
        self.points.append(point)

line1 = line()
line2 = line()
line1.add("Some point")
print line2.points
```

Output: `['Some point']`

And the result is like they refers to the same list.
But I do want a object member not a class member.

And I tried, if points is int, or some other simple type it works fine.

Besides, I know if I write

```
def __init__(self) :
    self.points = []
```

it will also work, but I don't get why they are pointing to same list by default.

ps. I know writing a init will work.

```
class line :
    name = "abc"

    def changename(self, name) :
        self.name = name

line1 = line()
line2 = line()
line1.changename(123)
print line2.name
```

But the code above output `"abc"`

So I don't understand why same kind of declaration act different by type.

Comment: This is a very common question, and a bit tricky to wrap your head around.  here's another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12161799/748858) asked yesterday to the same effect.  Perhaps another few explanations will help solidify the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in this case

```
class line :
    points = []
```

`points` is a *class* member. It belongs to the class, and since `line1` and `line2` are of the same *class*, `points` is the same list.

So you are right in using

```
def __init__(self) :
    self.points = []
```

instead to create an *instance* member which is tied to the instance, not the class.

**To answer your edit**

If you write:

```
def changename(self, name) :
    self.name = name
```

you override your class member and *create a new instance member* using `self.name = name`.

To get back to your first example, it would be like writing:

```
def add(self, point) :
    self.points = self.points + [point]
```

Comment: But if points is not a list object, say it is a string or int then it will not become a class member?

Comment: @black_dragon I added another sample in the question. If it is a string, it don't become a class member.

Comment: @silvesthu Yes, it does. But you just overrite it with an instance member. See my update.

Answer (score 2):

The first syntax:

```
class line :
    points = []
```

makes `points` a **class** attribute. Therefore, it will be shared between all instances of the class.

To make sure that an attribute belongs to a class, you should do as follows:

```
class line(object) :
    def __init__(self):
        self.points = []
```

i.e., creating the attributed only in `__init__`, when a new instance is created.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already explained, and as you apparently already understand, the following creates a **class** attribute, shared by every instance:

```
class line:
    points = []
```

When you **reference** this attribute in your code, Python attempts to find it the current scope, and then follows the enclosing scopes. So if you call `self.points.append()`, you are indeed changing the `points` **class** attribute.

When you **assign** to `self.points` in your code, you are defining a *new* `points` **instance** attribute. So in your second example when `points` is a string, the `changename` function actually creates a new instance attribute when called.

You can try the following:

```
print line.name  # prints the class attribute
print line1.name # prints the class attribute
print line2.name # prints the instance attribute
```

You will notice that calling `changename` did create a new instance attribute, while the class attribute is left unchanged. As `changename` was never called on `line1`, a reference to its `name` will resolve to the `line` class attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Mostly I use C++/Java so it took me a while to understand the "replace a attribute". I think I understand it now.