# object destruction in python

Tags: python, singleton, destructor

I am relatively new to python. Let me put my doubt in an example:

I create my class object called "person"

```
class person:
    name = ""
    age = ""
    phones = []
    def add_phone(self, number):
        self.phones.append(number)
```

let's prepare some data to be used later on:

```
names = ["jhon", "tony", "mike", "peter"]
ages = [34, 36, 23, 75]
phones = [7676, 7677, 7678, 7679]
```

Let's enter a for loop:

```
for i in range(0,4):
    new_person = person()
```

To my understanding, every time the preceding line is executed a new object person is created and called new_person, and any object in the variable new_person from a previous iteration should be destroyed. However this is not the case:

```
    new_person.name = names[i]
    new_person.age = ages[i]
    new_person.add_phone(phones[i])

    print "i= " + str(i)
    print "name= "+ new_person.name
    print "age= "+ str(new_person.age)
    print "phones:"
    print new_person.phones
```

`new_person.phones` contains the phones that we have added in previous iterations. Does anybody see what I am missing? Does this mean that the object class "person" behaves like a singleton?

Comment: Thats because your defining phones as a class level variable not an instance level varible

Comment: Have a look at this old post.  It might clear some things up for you:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/12161799/748858

Comment: thanks, I have just understood that "data tributes" (what are called "data members in c++) declared in the class are "static", all is clear now although I feel a bit awkward.

Comment: Be careful with the word "static"—it doesn't mean quite the same thing in C++ and Python. (Well, it means 4 different things in C++, but none of them are the same as in Python.) In Python, "class" means "belongs to the class rather than the instance", while "static" means "belongs to neither, and is just attached here for convenience". (This mainly matters for methods, not data members.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objects are getting created and destroyed as you'd expect. The problem is that `self.phones` belongs to the *class* rather than the *instance* and is therefore shared by all instances of `person`.

To fix, change your class like so:

```
class person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.age = ""
        self.phones = []
    def add_phone(self, number):
        self.phones.append(number)
```

Comment: Careful using the word `property` as that's a built-in function/decorator that returns a descriptor.  Can I suggest the term `attribute` instead?

Comment: +1 to @mgilson. Attribute, member, data member, variable, or just about anything else is fine, just not property.

Comment: I like `attribute` as it makes sense with the names of other builtins -- `getattr`, `setattr`, `delattr` ...

Comment: thanks, I have just understood that "data tributes" (what are called "data members in c++) declared in the class are "static" except you "declare" them in a method. All is clear now although I feel a bit awkward, seems too much flexible for me!

Comment: @mgilson: Yes, but `attribute` also includes methods (and classmethods, staticmethods, and custom descriptors), which can be confusing for new users. And some of the other terms are familiar from other languages, as well as being more specific. So it's not one-size-fits-all. It's just that "property" fits none… (I like NPE's solution of not using _any_ word, by the way.)

Comment: @user1862963: No need to feel awkward. It's one of those gotchas everyone runs into at one point or another.

Answer (score 2):

You're defining a bunch of class-level attributes that should almost certainly be instance level.  I think what you want is:

```
class person:

    def __init__(self):

        self.name = ""
        self.age = ""
        self.phones = []

    def add_phone(self, number):

        self.phones.append(number)
```

The way instantiation is handled in Python is that the initializer `__init__()` (similar to but not the same as a constructor in other languages) creates instance attributes.  In Python it's probably more common to set uninitialized attributes to `None` rather than empty strings.  Also, it's common to include frequently-used attributes in the initializer:

```
    def __init__(self, name = None, age = None, phones = None):

        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        if phones = None:
            self.phones = []
        else:
            self.phones = phones
```

Comment: Why does he want the class variables with the same name as the instance variables? That's just making things more confusing.

Comment: He doesn't -- he wants someone who proofreads when he cuts-and-pastes from the original question.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you. Now that I am stating to understand how python classes work, I see that calling the class variables with the same name as the instance variables might be confusing. i am used to that in c++ where the scope and the data members declaration makes it so clear that calling them with the same name even helps!. I am impressed with the quantity and the high level of the answers, you solved my doubt in less than a minute.

Comment: @user1862963: Actually, in C++, you can't name a static data member and a regular data member the same thing. In Python, you sort of can (but remember that these are actually _class_, not _static_ members), but you will almost certainly confuse yourself.

Comment: Outside of a very specialized application (that models a world in which all people are clones of one original person but have their own home and cell phone numbers) I can't think of any situation in which you would want a `person` class with class-level name and age attributes.

Answer (score -1):

To work as expected, you need to define `phones` as instance attribute.

```
class person:
    name = ""
    age = ""
    def __init__(self):
        self.phones = []
    def add_phone(self, number):
        self.phones.append(number)
```

In your example, you append phone to class attribute, which is "shared" for all instances (as to say).

Comment: This doesn't allow a person to have more than 1 phone ;-).

Comment: And it also makes all people share the same `name` and `age`…

Comment: @abarnert -- Only if they're unset.  `person().age = 30` won't influence any of the other people.

Comment: @mgilson: Well, yeah, in the same way that `person.add_phone('1234567')` followed by `person.phones.append('4567890')` allows a person to have two phones. The fact that he has a class attribute named `age` implies that he intends to use it.

Comment: @mgilson Just can't understand why. `p = person(); p.phones.append("132")`. Oh, I see...